# Cambiar icono .exe native packaging javafx

Tags: java, javafx

tengo un problema con el icono de un .exe generado de un paquete nativo javafx. Me aparece el icono de Java en vez del de la aplicación. Como podría cambiarlo???

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Busca en el proyecto el CRMBASIC.ico y cambialo por el de tu aplicación

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, lo busco esta noche y comento que tal.

Comment: Hola @Ajeno, no me detecta el .ico, en que ruta debería ponerlo para que lo pille. Para la aplicación en sí, tengo los .png en un paquete de assets. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

para esto puedes auxiliarte de la herramienta gratuita [Launch4J](https://sourceforge.net/projects/launch4j/). Es muy sencilla de usar y efectiva, además te puedes encontrar montones de tutoriales en internet. Yo personalmente, la he usado en mis proyectos JavaFX con muy buenos resultados. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, deberías indicar como estas generando ese .exe. Entiendo que lo estás generando con la utilidad javapackager que viene en el jdk, ya sea directamente o con un plugin de maven por ejemplo. Esta utilidad recibe un parámetro -Bicon={ruta de tu icono}. Yo en mi proyecto (usando maven) tengo algo así:

```
<executable>${jdk.home}bin/javapackager</executable>

<arguments>
   <argument>-deploy</argument>
   <argument>-native</argument>
   <argument>-outdir</argument>
   ...
   <argument>-vendor</argument>
   <argument>${app.vendor}</argument>
   <argument>-Bicon=${project.build.directory}/..${icon.bundle}</argument>
   <argument>-BappVersion=${app.version}</argument>
   ...
</arguments>
```

Siendo la variable ${icon.bundle} la que te afecta directamente y que en mi caso es dependiente del OS en el que quiero generar el ejecutable (OSX y Windows):

```
    <profile>
        <id>windows</id>
        <properties>          
          <icon.bundle>\src\main\deploy\package\windows\Icono.ico</icon.bundle>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>mac</id>
        <properties>
            <icon.bundle>/src/main/deploy/package/macosx/Icono.icns</icon.bundle>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda. Si no puedes consultar la doc oficial de javapackager.

Comment: Te doy más detalles, es un proyecto javafx y estoy utilizando packaging native para generar el exe. El caso es que el icono de la aplicación es un png que está en package. Y según tengo entendido para ponerlo en el exe debe ser un .ico en la raíz. De ahí la pregunta. Ya que no me lo muestra. Si lo tengo que añadir al build o algo.